# With regional locale, `pluralize` doesn't work but `translate` does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, locale

I've got this behaviour that I can't explain:

```
$ rails console 
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.7.1)
irb(main):001:0> I18n.locale
=> :"en-GB"
irb(main):002:0> I18n.available_locales
=> [:en, :"en-GB"]
irb(main):003:0> 'bear'.pluralize
=> "bears"
irb(main):004:0> 'bear'.pluralize(2, :"en-GB")
=> "bear" # <- sadness here
irb(main):005:0> 'bear'.pluralize(2, :en)
=> "bears"
irb(main):006:0> I18n.translate("gst")
=> "VAT" # <- correct translation from 'config/locales/en-GB.yml'
irb(main):007:0> ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize('bear', :en)
=> "bears"
irb(main):008:0> ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize('bear', :'en-GB')
=> "bear"
```

My `<rails_root>/uk/config/locales/en-GB.yml`:

```
en-GB:
  gst: VAT
```

How come the regionalised locale is available, in use, and works well with translations but not with pluralisation? Just in case, I've put 
`config.i18n.fallbacks = { :'en-GB' => :en }` in my `config/application.rb`, but without effect. I've got no clue on where I should investigate further...

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add this part of your locale files to the question, just as an assurance that it's stated correctly in the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this has been fixed in Rails 5 thanks to this [patch](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29097)